# Using multiple @parameters for JUNIT4

Tags: junit4

I am trying to write parameterize test in JUNIT4 and I don't know how to make multiple parameters for instance :

@parameter1
{1,2,3,4}

@test1
run test using @parameter1

@parameter2
{3,55,66,77}

@test2
run test using @parameters2

Could anyone provide me with a sample snippet, that would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you could take advantage of the [@Theories](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2010/01/31/new-feature-of-junit-theories/) and [@TestedOn](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/test/java/org/junit/tests/experimental/theories/ParameterSignatureTest.java).

```
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theory;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.suppliers.TestedOn;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class SuppliedByTest {

  @Theory
  public void test1(@TestedOn(ints = { 2, 3, 4, 7, 13, 23, 42 }) int i) {
     System.out.println(i);
  }

  @Theory
  public void test2(@TestedOn(ints = { 6, 3, 4, 7, 13, 23, 42 }) int i) {
     System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```