# How to write junit for "this" keywrd and for the following method. I only know basics and stuck with this

Tags: java, junit

Since am new to junit am finding it confusing for such methods. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
I am able to write testcases for some math operations, but not able to write for such methods.

```
public class ErrorThreshold {
    private String attributeType = null;
    private String errorCode = null;

    public ErrorThreshold()
    {

    }

    public ErrorThreshold(String attributeType,  String errorCode)
    {
        this.attributeType = attributeType;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getAttributeType() {
        return attributeType;
    }

    public void setAttributeType(String attributeType) {
        this.attributeType = attributeType;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: "junit for this keyword" .. "for the following method". writing "junit for this keyword" makes no sense at all, and so far, you've shown no code at all that warrants unit tests.

Comment: Do you have reason to distrust `this`? I'd just use the getters to fetch those values. I am quite confident a getter won't fail. If you do add some custom logic to the getter, then it's worth testing them if they work but otherwise it seems OK to assume they work.

Comment: @Stultuske yeah, I was also quite confused. As best I can guess, OP wants to test `this.errorCode` is called correctly and set. Or something along these lines. Although I do agree - there is hardly anything to test here. At best, I'd check that the default constructor ends up with `null` for both fields and a constructor with parameters sets them. It's not a lot but it's a somewhat reasinable test, to bind the expectation that `errorCode` would be `null` instead of, say, `"defaultErrorCode"` or something.

Comment: @VLAZ the only use to test the code is above, is to get higher "test-coverage". (the quote marks are intentional). There is nothing at all to test, the code can't go wrong. If it's code coverage the OP is concerned with, he should replace the constructor/getters/setters by alternatives generated by lombok.

Comment: @VLAZ for the sake of code coverage, do i have to test this or can i ignore it? But need to achieve max code coverage.

Comment: @Stultuske I agree that a test is rather useless. The one I suggested is quite a far stretch but the best and *only* one I can think of that is not exceptionally trivial. In truth, I wouldn't write that test *unless* the default `errorCode` or `attributeCode` is anything but `null`.

Comment: @Kraj I'd personally ignore it but it depends on your company - if it requires 100% test coverage, then you'll have to write some code just to exercise these. But it's just code for the sake of writing code.

Comment: @VLAZ let's assume they require 100% code coverage. by adding one or two lombok annotations, the setters, getters and constructor are generated, and without a single line of unit test code, 100% of that class is covered, since there is no code to cover ;)

Comment: @Stultuske can you provide a code snippet or hint using those lombok annotations?

Comment: @Kraj https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter

Comment: This solution answers the above query.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21355383/11291944