# Testing Return Statements

Tags: java, testing, junit, return

so I'm pretty new to JUnit testing so I'm a bit stuck here.
I have to test this method for an assignment but I'm nor sure how I would test a return statement. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public String getLvlCode() {
  return LvlCode;
}

public void setLvlCode(String lvlCode) {
  this.lvlCode = lvlCode;
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd method seems to be a `setter` (not `getter`). You may want to read the following in its entirety:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354311/junit-test-of-setters-and-getters-of-instance-variables

Comment: You execute the method and compare the result to the expected one. E.g. you define an input (obviously, you have to construct an instance of some unknown class and set the class variable `LvlCode`), then you execute the method and use some assertion (JUnit has several of them) to compare the result with the expected result.

Comment: putting get twice was a mistype after retyping the code...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class looks like this:

```
class Example {
    private String lvlCode;

    public String getLvlCode() {
        return LvlCode;
    }

    public void setLvlCode(String lvlCode) {
        this.lvlCode = lvlCode;
    }
}
```

One test you could write for it is:

```
import org.junit.Assert;

class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void testLvlCodeSetter() {
        final String EXPECTED_CODE = "ABCD_1234";
        Example example = new Example();
        example.setLvlCode(EXPECTED_CODE):

        Assert.assertEquals(EXPECTED_CODE, example.getLvlCode());
    }
}
```